# How Can a Remote Form Action URL Be Overridden?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

At URL **www.here.com/article1.htm**, I have Javascript that fills a modal with an HTML login form whose action is **www.not-here.com/login.php** and authentication works fine, except after completing the login.php action, the browser ends up at **www.not-here.com/login.php**, rather than remaining at the URL where the modal was activated, **www.here.com/article1.htm**.

To instruct the browser to remain at **www.here.com/article1.htm**, I first added id="loginTrigger" in the submit input tag like this:

```
<input id="loginTrigger" type="submit" name="doLogin" value="Login">
```

Then, in my Javascript I added a click event handler to override the form's default behavior and remain at the URL detected when the document loaded (modal Javascript is omitted for brevity):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  hereSecureURL = window.location.protocol;
  hereDomain = window.location.hostname;
  herePath = window.location.pathname;
  hereAnchor = window.location.hash;
  hereURL = hereSecureURL + '//' + hereDomain + herePath + hereAnchor;

  $('#trigger').click(function(e){
    modal.open({content: $form});
  });

  $('#loginTrigger').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = hereURL;
    modal.close();
  });
});
```

How can the browser be instructed to remain at **www.here.com/article1.htm** and just have the form process and modal close?

Comment: Why not redirect it back to the desired url from php itself using headers function?

Comment: I see two options: 1- redirect back from `login.php`; 2- send form through AJAX

Comment: I know what you're saying. For testing purposes, I did start with a hard-coded header, which worked, but the problem is I don't know what the source URL will be. I'm hoping for a less jump-through-hoops approach, but if there are no alternatives, how can hereURL get passed to login.php?

Comment: you may check the `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`variable, it contains "where the request came from", don't forget to make a fallback in case this variable is empty

Comment: Thanks Sanção. That does the trick. Too bad there is no way to disable the redirection and just remain at the referrer where the form was modally loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit a form action, it's making a `POST` call to your server. Once validated, your server should then redirect the person to wherever you want them to be.

Some people handle this using a `REFERRER` param in the `POST` call, then redirecting to that `REFERRER` after the user has been authenticated.

so essentially, you should be rendering your form with an action that looks something like this:

```
<form action="/login.php?REFERRER=/ThePageIwasOn"... >
```

Your server code would look something like this:

```
<form action="/login.php?REFERRER=<?php print $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] ?>" ...>
```

Of course, I don't know what kind of app server you're running, so YMMV.

By the way, this is just one of many ways to do this. If it were me, I'd probably store the value in a session. I don't like exposing values like this. It looks crummy.

Edit: As Sancao mentioned, it's not always a POST request... ok, whatever. Second, he's right, it'll be available in the $_GET variable, since it's a url param, and yes, it probably is better to hide it in an input, especially if you're working on HTTPS.

Comment: i suggest some improvements, not always forms are send by POST, it depends on `method` attribute. Also, if you put variables in action attribute it will be available in the `$_GET` variable. If a variable will be passed it's  better to use a hidden input

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies in this part

```
 $('#loginTrigger').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = hereURL;
    modal.close();
  });
```

you need to select your submit button by the parentID of the modal itself

then try modal.close(); , if didn't work try modal.toggle();
then you have to check against something in order to reveal information 
a cookie or whatever ,

another work around is to send a redirect header from the php after fully authentication to the 1.html page and write down a cookie to tell the browser that everything is fine to not display the modal again

Comment: Interesting idea, so I tried it. Clicking anywhere within the parenID element closed the modal, but the action did not fire. So, I removed e.preventDefault(), but then the modal closed and window.location = hereURL had no effect. The browser ended up at www.not-here.com/login.php. Still, this gives me a new idea. Maybe I should disable the action and use the click event to get the innerHTMLs of the username and password inputs, then post them to the login form straight from Javascript. Thank you for your help.

Comment: use var Data=$("#formID").serialize(); then send the Data Var through Ajax call , it will do what you want :)